# Update single JSP page element without using form

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts

In my Struts2/Java application, I am allowing the user to send in data to the application from JQGrid.  I am using the "saverow" function to loop through each selected row and submit the edited cells.  This function is in a separate js file which is included in my JSP.

```
function editRows(){


    for (...){
        ...
        ...
        ...
        jQuery('#myGrid').jqGrid('saveRow,rowID,false,null,null,aftersavefunc);
    }

    getResponse();

}
```

After the data is submitted from this function, a number of class variables in my action class are updated.  I use the aftersavefunc to set the value of hidden jqgrid cells (jqgrid 'setCell') so I can recall them later from the grid.

I have additional values which are simply displayed in a div.  These values are also updated within the application after it has been executed.  **At the time that I'm executing the editRows() function mentioned above, the following div is already visible and displaying a value for each of the fields within the div.**  These initial div values are the result of a previous form being submitted.  Here's what the div looks like in my JSP.

```
<div id="headerBar">
  <table>
      <tr>
          <td>Total Items:  <s:property value="strutsActionName.totalItems</td>
          ...
          ...
          ...
      </tr>
  </table>      
</div>
```

So for instance, when my function editRows is being executed, the div is already showing a value for "totalItems" on the webpage.  It would just look something like this:

```
Total Items:  5
```

After function editRows has executed, the value of "totalItems" has been updated within the application.  The java action class has the latest value for totalRows.

The editRows function is calling another function getResponse() when the loop has finished.  The getResponse function is for obtaining the hidden jqgrid values that I set using the "aftersavefunc" parameter of "saverow".  It uses the jqGrid('getCell') to get the updated value of those hidden jqGrid cells.

I want to have the getResponse() function to also refresh the value of "totalItems".  This value is not in a jqGrid.  I need to refresh the individual field and obtain the updated value.  For instance, after editRows() has completed, the value of "totalItems" could have been doubled to 10 from 5.

Within my getResponse() function, I've tried updating this value by using the following, but it hasn't worked.

```
document.getElementById('headerBar').reload
```

I just need to update the values in this div without submitting a form.

Answer (score 0):

The property tag is processed on the server side so it would not be updated until request is sent to the server.

As i see it the best way for doing this would be to put the property value inside an element with an id like span or p and then use document.getElemenrById to retrieve that element element and change its content from javascript after retrieving its new value.

Comment: just need some clarification.  you said change it 'from' javascript.  not sure exactly what you mean.  So i'll have <span id="totalItems><td><s property...</td></span>.  Then getElementById(totalItems).reload.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes more or less but put span inside td so you can change the text alone